# Operational Transformation library?

Tags: etherpad, operational-transform

I'm looking for a library that would allow me to synchronize text in real-time between multiple users (ala Google Docs).

I've stumbled upon Operational Transformation, which seems to fit my needs. Having said that, I understand the gist of OT, but not the math nor implementation of OT.

Thus, I was wondering if there was a drag'n'drop Javascript library that would hook into a text area, generate the transforms, then allow me to apply those transformations onto another client?

(I've gotten the Etherpad source, but I can't make head or tails out of it. If anyone could point out how to leverage on Etherpad's OT implementation, that'll be great too!)

Comment: Collaborative text editor powered by Firebase called Firepad - https://firepad.io/ Check the code to get some inspiration https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firepad

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think that parts of Google Wave's OT implementation are Open Source (and more parts are coming).

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but an alternative to OT is [Differential Synchronization](http://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/):

- [Google-Diff-Match-Patch - Diff, Match and Patch libraries for Plain Text](http://Google-Diff-Match-Patch.GoogleCode.Com/): "*The Diff Match and Patch libraries offer robust algorithms to perform the operations required for synchronizing plain text.*"
- [Google-MobWrite - Real-time Synchronization and Collaboration Service](http://Google-MobWrite.GoogleCode.Com/): "*MobWrite converts forms and web applications into collaborative environments. Create a simple single-user system, add one line of JavaScript, and instantly get a collaborative system.*" (Uses Google-Diff-Match-Patch.)

Comment: Diff-Match-Patch, combined with the Differential Synchronization paper by Neil Frasier (http://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/) did the trick!

Many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: From what I understand, Diff-Match-Patch, and by extension, MobWrite (since the latter uses the former) only supports text, not binary changes. However, there is a demo of collaboration with HTML form elements, which would indicate it doesn't only support plain text.

Comment: Any good news on "and more parts are coming" since this answer ?

Comment: Actually, Google-Diff-Match-Patch is aimed to implement the alternative method to Operational Transformations, which is Differential Synchronization, to understand the differences you can read the Neil Fraser document of DS: http://neil.fraser.name/writing/sync/ (OT is referenced in this document as Event passing).
They are two very different methods.

Comment: this is old, but in case you mind, I have opensourced https://github.com/benjamine/JsonDiffPatch it uses Neil's Diff-Match-Patch for long strings, but it works for arbritrary js object graphs

Comment: Operational transformation intends to solve synchronization problem by only sending the change operations instead of the entire text to avoid huge network traffic. However DiffMatchPatch requires entire text of different versions to compute the difference. They are not achieving the same thing.

Comment: Neil Fraser's site is down. You can find the refernced article also here: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/35605.pdf
And you can find his Google tech talk here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S2Hp_1jqpY8

Answer (score 44):

One of the ex-Wave engineers has released a Coffeescript implementation of its collaborative editing algorithm called ShareJS, now named [ShareDB](https://github.com/share/sharedb).

Comment: ShareJS is probably simpler and better documented and more reusable than what MobWrite does with Google's Diff and Patch.

Answer (score 44):

I'll summarize the solutions I found.

- Operational Transformation: E.g.

  - Google Wave OT. The approach is based on the so called Jupiter approach.
  - ShareJs. Based on the same OT algorithm as Google Wave OT.
  - Coweb-jsoe. Based on COT - a very sophisticated OT approach that also supports p2p message propagation.
  - OpenCoweb. It leverages OpenCoweb-jsoe in order to provide a full-fledged Framework for a lot of similar problems.
  - OT.js is based on the operation-types of ShareJs.
  - DriveSDK. A very interesting API that can do a lot of things - e.g. collaboration on graphs.
  - SwellRT is a Fork of Apache Wave. Is is federated, and supports rich text.
- Differential Synchronization:

  - Diff-Match-Patch from Neil Fraser.
  - MobWrite leverages the Diff-Match-Patch algorithm.
- [CRDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type) (Commutative Replicated Data Type):

  - There are a lot of different CRDT algorithms that allow the implementation of shared types. Some CRDTs work with P2P message propagation, some rely on client-server models
  - [Yjs](https://github.com/y-js/yjs) allows you to share arbitrary data types (RichText, Array, Hash Maps, .. extendable). Offline support and support for P2P communication protocols (there are modules for XMPP, Websockets, and WebRTC)
  - [SwarmJS](https://github.com/gritzko/swarm) Client server shared database with offline support. Works well with React
  - [Woot](https://bitbucket.org/d6y/woot) An implementation of the Woot CRDT
  - [CRDT](https://github.com/dominictarr/crdt) Another CRDT implementation
  - [Automerge](https://github.com/automerge/automerge)

Comment: Google Drive API uses OT not DS. https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/conflict-resolution

Answer (score 6):

OT Libraries:

- https://github.com/sveith/jinfinote
- https://github.com/jvanveen/py-infinote

Within the HWIOS websocket project, i've succesfully used a combo of both(py-infinote at the serverside, jinfinote at clientside) to sync document states.

Answer (score 5):

The ot.js library  https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js may be useful for multi-user scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

https://github.com/opencoweb/coweb

Answer (score 4):

Turnkey, or "drag and drop" solutions to this problem haven't really existed due to the complexity of reliably synchronizing shared mutable state.  dmonad's response is a decent roundup, and I posted a more up-to-date overview of the available solutions [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-good-frameworks-for-real-time-collaboration-in-a-web-application).

This question is quite old, but [Convergence](https://convergence.io) (disclaimer: I am a founder) provides the most turnkey solution out there, providing not just data synchronization but a host of other APIs useful for building out a collaborative UX.  [Here is an example](https://convergence.io/tutorial/) showing exactly what you requested: synchronization of a text field across multiple clients.

Otherwise, [ShareDB](https://github.com/share/sharedb) is a great open-source solution that fits a lot of people's needs.

Answer (score 2):

Also check out these Javascript Libraries:

- https://github.com/vitotafuni/JSOTTEST < Client-side Javascript Implementation
- https://github.com/fitzgen/operational-transformation-example   < Node JS Client/Server Implementation

Answer (score 2):

Npm has some nice ot libraries for node.js:

- https://npmjs.org/package/ot -- adapters for codemirror and ace built in as well as a client and server implementation
- https://npmjs.org/package/changesets -- plain ot library usable in node and the browser; allows you to build 'changesets' (essentially diffs) that you can send around, transform against each other and apply on a document

Answer (score 2):

I have written a small unixy (do one thing and do it well) library that implements an OT control layer, allowing you to plug in different OT types (supports all shareJS compliant types).
It's similar to shareJS but less opinionated and more abstract.

https://github.com/marcelklehr/gulf

Answer (score 1):

You could talk to the guys at [Cedanet](http://www.cedanet.com.au/).  Though Ceda is closed source and no free trial is available on their web site.  I have been involved in the development of Ceda and continue to work with it in commercial projects, so I might be able to provide some feedback/advice if you head down this path.

Answer (score 1):

With a js client lib (Strophe.js) you could use a free XMPP server (like jabber.org) along with my client-side OT lib (JSOTTEST) to build a complete client-server system.

I will submit the src of a demo client-server chat system when I have time to revise the code.

Comment: Almost two years ago you write "I will submit the src of a demo...". Did you ever finish that demo?

Comment: Sorry... but I had no time to release a public demo! However it's very simple using Bosh lib for php!! bye

Answer (score 1):

We're building a collaborate editor that combines Operational Transformation with versioning. That way we can support both, offline and online collab. We released our own OT library yesterday as part of our open source stack.

http://interior.substance.io/modules/operator.html

We've also contributed a library for versioning.

http://interior.substance.io/modules/chronicle.html

Answer (score 0):

I thing etherpad.org with etherpad lite is superior to other solutions.

Comment: Would you be able to substantiate etherpad's superiority with some example?