# Commutative (operational transform) diffs for databases

Tags: etherpad, operational-transform

What Unix program generates "diff"s between text files (or 
INSERT/UPDATE/DELETEs for databases) in such a way that the order that          the "diff"s are applied in is irrelevant, and the result is the same 
regardless of order.

Etherpad used to do something like this.

Example (for a given document or database):

% Adam makes a change X, then Bob makes a change Y, then Adam makes 
 another change Z.

% However, because of network latency, Adam sees the changes in this 
 order: XZY, while Bob sees them in this order: YXZ.

% However, the code/changes are written so that XYZ and YXZ yield the 
 same result.

Note: ideally, this can be done without having to do X/Y/Z inverse at any 
point.

I have read [Operational Transformation library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043165/operational-transformation-library)
but I'm not sure this really does what I want.

Comment: OT is certainly what you're after, especially to get the "XYZ == YXZ"  that you want.  I just added an answer to the question you linked to that might help, though Ceda currently has no *nix port.

Answer (score 0):

[Git](http://git-scm.org) (or any smart version control system) will provide this functionality.

Comment: I hadn't thought about it, but I think you're right. Except, in this case, we're doing it character-by-character instead of line by line (and using an optimized version of "diff" to send deltas?).

OK, how would we do this w/ an SQL database, short of storing it as text files?