# Operational Transform Implementation (not javascript)

Tags: java, ruby, operational-transform

I'm looking to implement multi-user [operational transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) just for plain-text based changes on the server-side on a web-site.

Is there a non-javascript implementation that you can recommend?

Comment: Google wave libaries here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043165/operational-transformation-library/2043367#2043367

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider Google-Diff-Match-Patch - Diff, Match and Patch libraries for Plain Text:

"The Diff Match and Patch libraries offer robust algorithms to perform the operations required for synchronizing plain text."

Diff: Compare two blocks of plain text and efficiently return a list of differences.

Diff Demo
Match: Given a search string, find its best fuzzy match in a block of plain text. Weighted for both accuracy and location.

Match Demo
Patch: Apply a list of patches onto plain text. Use best-effort to apply patch even when the underlying text doesn't match.

Patch Demo
Currently available in Java, JavaScript, C++, C#, Objective C, Lua and Python. Regardless of language, each library features the same API and the same functionality. All versions also have comprehensive test harnesses.

You can find it [here](http://google-diff-match-patch.googlecode.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Consider Py-infinote.

py-infinote is a python port of JInfinote, offering a collaborative text-editing protocol(adOPTed) which can be used to write multi-user collaborative text editors. Py-infinote is used in the HWIOS project.

https://github.com/sveith/jinfinote

Answer (score 0):

This is another quite interesting implementation integrating google wave's operational transform with jedit:

https://github.com/djspiewak/cccp

Answer (score 0):

OpenCoweb is a popular OT implementation. There are several server implementations written in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Simple reference implementation which I will be improving next few months by adding more complex stuff;

Now it has:

- simple text operations; retain, insert, delete and their transformations against each other
- annotations over text and transformations
- generation of changes and applying them to text

https://github.com/slevental/operational-transformation