# Collaborative editing algorithm for java web application

Tags: java, javascript, tomcat, collaboration, collaborative

I have a Java (Apache Tomcat) based web application which allows user to write code in browser in different languages like (c, c++, java) and compile and execute them on server. The server security issues are handled by executing every code in chroot jail under ptrace supervision.

- I'm using Ace editor as code editor.

I want to add another feature that is **collaborative editing**, name says it all.

I have seen some [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086699/real-time-collaborative-editing-how-does-it-work) questions on **Stack Overflow**.

So if I use [code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/), and generate a diff every 0.5 seconds, send it to the server and pull all the other diffs and return them from the server.

- Do you think above approach would work? Will it be feasible?
- I have this web application ready, so i only want someone to point me in right direction so that i can integrate some java script and write some Server side code to achieve my **GOAL**.
- What will be the best way to add Collaborative Editing in my web
  application?

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on a very similar project. :)

Your solution does not handle the conflicts. You need a more sophisticate technique like operational transformation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation

---

It was the base of Google Wave that now is open source:

http://www.waveprotocol.org/protocol

http://incubator.apache.org/wave/

---

In Internet you can find a lot of good blogs and articles about this topic:
http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/understanding-and-applying-operational-transformation