# (web) How to synchronize users concurrently editing a textarea?

Tags: python, web, concurrency, textarea, bottle

I have a TextArea '**TA**' in my website where users can edit its text concurrently.

What I have done so far is the following,

- I set a global variable '**content**' in the server side to capture/monitor the value of the **TA**
- A javascript Ajax function '**JU**' that stores the value of the **TA** to the
  variable 'content' for any change in the **TA**. In other words, if the
  user types anything in the **TA**, the content value gets updated (content=TA.value)via the onkey() function
- A javascript Ajax function '**JR**' that reads the variable 'content' every second to update TA using TA.value=content

However, with this approach I'm facing the race condition or similar issues. For instance, if I write quickly in the **TA**, some of the letters gets removed because the **TA** reads the variable '**content**' to update its value before it stores what I wrote to 'content'

I tried tricks such as resetting the timer of **JR** for updating **TA** everytime the user types, however, the issue persists, albeit less. Furthermore, with this approach if a user keeps typing he wouldn't see what other users are writing until later...

Thanks in advance!

PS: I'm using python as the server-side language (bottle framework)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086699/real-time-collaborative-editing-how-does-it-work and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043165/operational-transformation-library