# Implementing a collaborative real-time mapping application

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bing-maps, collaboration

What's the best approach for implementing a real-time collaborative mapping application? What are possible different approaches to build it on top of the Google or Bing maps API, and do these APIs provide any convenient ways to aggregate data from different users? I can imagine that there are different levels of integration with a maps API itself, and possible existing software that does similar things. Any pointers or tips would be helpful.

**Background**: Google Docs and other collaborative editing software allow a group of people to edit a document in real time, and takes care of things such as simultaneous input and displaying the progress and cursor of other users. I want to do something similar with a mapping application, where a bunch of people can tag and annotate locations on a map, together, in real time. The idea is to support large-scale crowdsourced mapping immediately after natural disasters or other large events where a huge amount of geographical data needs to be mapped and classified.

This app needs to run in the browser. The level of synchronicity doesn't have to be as integrated as Google docs - i.e., as long as things appear on the map in real-time, we don't necessarily have to see where users are editing and where they are typing. However, it does need to be integrated with a maps API so it is more challenging than using a straight collaborative text editor, for which examples are available.

In searching around, I found example source code for many types of [collaborative text editing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5086699/586086), of which the best example of a web app with source code available was [Etherpad](http://etherpad.org/). However, I need to apply this idea to a mapping problem. What are possible ways to build a real-time app on top of a maps API and pointers to existing examples?

**UPDATE**: For people who are interested, I ended up building this with OpenLayers on top of Meteor: https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper. Feel free to check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Not a complete answer by any stretch, but people are doing cool things with [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com):

http://www.fargeo.com/blog/using-meteor-for-real-time-geospatial-data/

http://meteor.com/#examples/parties

Comment: +1 The reference to Meteor with the real-time geospatial map is pretty awesome. It's amazing that he created that in a couple of hours. Will look into it more!

Answer (score 1):

Given your provided use-case scenario, you could try contacting the humanitarian response team at Open Street Map, who use OSM as a collaborative map data collection and dissemination tool in crisis response situations: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Humanitarian_OSM_Team

It's not strictly realtime, but if you host your own OSM server you could set map tiles to be regenerated every time updates were submitted and all users would then receive the latest view of the map.

Comment: Thanks. The Meteor app that Shaun linked to is real-time and also uses OSM, so I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly simple.

- Step 1.  Create a database that houses the entries
- Step 2.  Create a
  map that populates the points from the records in the database
- Step 3.  Create an interface for people to add items to the database (in real-time).

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 are pretty obvious. What I'm asking for are more details on how to do step 3. How do you do things in real time? Do maps APIs synchronize annotations or will that need to be done as a separate layer on top of the map? etc.

Comment: Polling would be the way to go.  Have a webservice that returns any new entries, and have the page with map poll that webservice in regular intervals.  Then parse the json response and insert those as markers into the map.

Comment: Polling? You must be kidding. Websocket and other bidirectional technologies have made polling obsolete. Take a look at what Shaun posted, it's very similar to what I need to do.

Comment: Hey, you're the one asking me to write your site for you.  If you don't want my help that's fine.  Maybe you should try doing some actual work before asking people what to do.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot! Going ahead and coding with no thought about design or tools is definitely the best way to make progress on a project!

Comment: I think you're confused about where you are.  Look around you chief.  Notice all the code attempts before asking for help.  Notice how you're just being a jerk. Notice, your negative votes...  Sorry I tried to help you.  I never thought you would be so ungrateful for a stranger trying to give you give you honest help.  Luckily your in the minority.  Most people appreciate others take time out of their day to help.

Comment: I didn't mean to come across as a jerk. I just didn't know what to make of your three-bullet answer and comments that were quite unhelpful and came across as sarcastic. I was asking for design decisions and input from others who have implemented similar applications. I don't think this is a case where I have a simple programming question and you want to see a code snippet. For a similar question that was answered well, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12310024/586086.

Answer (score 0):

Back-end solutions for implementing the collaboration part would be google realtime api 
https://developers.google.com/drive/realtime/realtime-quickstart

and also firebase:
https://www.firebase.com/how-it-works.html

I dont know how this would be implemented, but if you know how to store the edits of the map on a datastructure, all you need to do is tie that data structure with one of the above APIs and you are basically almost done.

Comment: Meteor turned out to be the perfect data structure. It plays well with any non-realtime APIs as well with the right callbacks hooked up.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-05032001-113750/unrestricted/FinalThesis.pdf
You can go through this PDF.
It gives you an insight of what and how a collaborative editor works.
It gives details about architecture and design they are using.