# How to Track user cursor with name in real time editor?

Tags: javascript, css, express, real-time, sharejs

I am following this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/building-a-real-time-markdown-viewer , to create a real time editor. And I want to add and build a Google Doc like feature to track the User cursor text which has unique color like this[Different colored cursor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udj0s.jpg)

And to show only newly added text to the pad highlighted, so that the viewer is able to identify the newly added changes to the pad.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need something to sync the cursor position among all colaborators. It can be done using [WebSockets](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiC_e6GkP3LAhVHxpAKHRRtCnwQFggxMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fes%2Fdocs%2FWebSockets-840092-dup&usg=AFQjCNHgEn0ap39kI1ZoJJFe9yGxITLRzQ&sig2=9PFsNO7YSGIU5aCLS9bJ9g). That, for starters. Still, I think you can have more info here: [Real time collaborative editing - how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086699/real-time-collaborative-editing-how-does-it-work?rq=1)