# Multiple people collaboratively editing file at the same time with AJAX/PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm making a collaborative editor for websites, much like Google Docs, but it's built for coding and development. I want to allow multiple users to edit a file at the same time, and push their changes both to the server and the other person viewing the file. How could I do this?

I can't figure out how to synchronize the data between users. The code I have right now is as follows:
AJAX in JS:

```
function update(f, txt){
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     data: {text: txt, file: f},
     url: "save.php",
   });
}
```

save.php:

```
$file = $_POST['file'];
$contents = $_POST['text'];
file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/preview" . "/" . $file,$contents);
```

Comment: What code have you tried to resolve the inquiry?

Comment: My current code has it that it updates the file every so often while one of the users is typing, but I have nothing to handle grabbing and syncing this data through multiple clients that have it open, which is why I'm here. I'll post some of the code I have though

Comment: Real time updates will require you to call `setTtimeout` in javascript to update what someone else may have edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EventSource` to stream data from server to browser or `WebSocket` to stream data both to server and from server. That is, each client receives the stream of the file continuously, see for example [How to read and echo file size of uploaded file being written at server in real time without blocking at both server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475492/how-to-read-and-echo-file-size-of-uploaded-file-being-written-at-server-in-real).

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co) provides a real time sharing option and is open source. Consider locating and reading the code for that application and adjusting for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Drew `WebRTC` or browser extensions are also options that you can try, see [Method for streaming data from browser to server via HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35899536/)

Comment: I'd like to stay away from browser extensions, it creates an extra step for the user to take to use the service

Comment: @Drew If the the application is "built for coding and development" the "extra step" of a browser extension should not be an issue for the client. There are several options available which can meet requirement, including `git` at the commandline and, or using [GitHub](https://github.com); or utilizing `http/2` at server. What issues are you having with the current code?

Comment: @Drew Given the code at Question you presently can stream the resulting file to each client as `"text/event-stream"` from server and get the stream using `EventSource` `message` event. At client you can use `ReadableStream`, `WritableStream` and possibly `TransformStream` to process the stream from server to re-build the file.

Comment: @Drew Have you read the links at "Related" at the current page, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5086699/real-time-collaborative-editing-how-does-it-work?rq=1 ?