# Integrating an operational transformation library with Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, collaboration, real-time-updates, operational-transform

When building apps with Meteor, its capabilities have really amazed me. However, to be able to drop in Etherpad-style collaborative editing bits into my app would really be a holy grail.

While looking up how to do this, I found some projects that seem to use OT libraries in meteor.

Projects using [ot.js](https://github.com/Operational-Transformation/ot.js/):

- https://github.com/TeamCocoDojo/cocodojo (Demo at http://cocodojo.meteor.com)

Projects using [ShareJS](https://github.com/share/ShareJS):

- https://github.com/mad-eye/meteor-sharejs (Demo at http://madeye.io/)

I can't seem to tell how these projects integrate with Meteor. Are they actually using Meteor Collections? Do they just use the Node server that is hosting Meteor and do the OT as a separate component, not using Meteor at all? Is there a different OT library that integrates better with Meteor?

If anyone is familiar with these projects or has implemented OT as part of a Meteor app, please share your thoughts on the best way to approach this.

(This isn't a duplicate of [Operational Transformation in Meteor.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11594043/586086) as that question is almost a year old and Meteor has moved a long way since then.)

Answer (score 1):

I've started the process of integrating ShareJS with Meteor via a smart package:

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs

Please try it out in your Meteor app, and submit new features!

Demo here:

> http://documents.meteor.com